# Is there something wrong with my for loop for f(x)?

Tags: python

I am trying to code a function that returns `f(x)` as shown in the image below

[image]

However when I insert the inputs `N` and `x`, I keep on getting the wrong answer.

I suspect that maybe it has something to do with my summation in the function but I am not sure where exactly. I tried using the `import math.fsum` to shorten the length of the function and maybe that would have affected the answer.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Here is my code for `f(x)` and the derivative of `f(x)` which is included in the function:

```py
from math import sin, cos, pi, fsum

def f(x, N):
    for i in range(1, N):

        h = (x/N) + pi/(2*N)
        p = (-pi/2) + i*h     
        y = (h/2)*(df(-pi/2) + df(x)) + h*fsum([df(p) for i in range(1, N)])  

        return(y)


def df(x): 

    d = (3*cos(x)) / ((2 + sin(x))**2)

    return(d)
```

Comment: In what way does your code produce the "wrong answer"?

Comment: Hm, can you post the formula in a better quality? It's quite hard to read

Comment: A `for` loop with an unconditional `return` inside it is pointless - only the first iteration of the loop will ever execute.

Comment: @ScottHunter I am using these functions as part of another function (which i don't think has an error)  that returns the roots of f(x) through newtons method however the roots I get are incorrect

Comment: @RolandDeschain hi, I just edited the post.. sorry for that

Comment: @jasonharper ah I see what you mean... thank you for that :)

Answer (score 2):

Python 2 vs Python 3? I case you run different interpreters, you might have just cut off the floating point part of the number with division. Rewrite every divisor in the division to a `float`.

And since I don't see any loop except the sum in the formula, I believe you need to remove the `for` loop completely and keep only the `fsum(...)` part to keep the sum and the formula in tact:

```
def f(x, N):
    h = (x / float(N)) + pi / float(2 * N)
    p = (-pi / 2.0) + i * h
    y = (h / 2.0) * (df(-pi / 2.0) + df(x)) + h * fsum([df(p) for i in range(1, N)])  
    return y
```

As mentioned in the comments by @jasonharper, the loop does nothing anyway since you'd only get the first iteration as with my rewrite.

The `math.fsum()` does nothing else except summing the values in an `IEEE-754` floating point standard:

```
>>> sum([.1, .1, .1, .1, .1, .1, .1, .1, .1, .1])
0.9999999999999999
>>> fsum([.1, .1, .1, .1, .1, .1, .1, .1, .1, .1])
1.0
```

[source](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.fsum)

Comment: Thank you for this Peter! makes a lot of sense

Comment: @villematicc glad to help